# How to add events with NativeBase components

Tags: react-native, native-base

What events are available for the NativeBase components?

Say for example,

- Update the state on the input on onChangeText
- I would like to respond to Button clicks while submitting a form

What other events those mentioned in [React Native](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/) are supported with the [NativeBase](http://nativebase.io/) components?

Answer (score 13):

This should be as simple as using the onPress method props on the button component:

```
<Button style={{ backgroundColor: 'grey'}} onPress={() =>alert('Add payment')} block >
<Icon name="ios-add-circle-outline" />
ADD PAYMENT
</Button>
```

Comment: im trying to add a function that i have in my class and it's telling me that the function isn't found, if i add "this.functionName()" throws a `stack size execeeded`. What is it wrong?

Answer (score 2):

All the props which are supported by touchable opacity in react native are supported by button component. button component justs adds some extra props along with touchable opacity.